# Higher bound for prime numbers

Tags: number-theory

Hello I'd like to know if this is true

$p_{n+2}\leq 4(1+2+...+n)+4$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

$p_{n+2}$ is the $(n+2)$-th prime number.

Comment: Do you believe it's true?  Why or why not?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  It would improve your Question to show what effort you made to research the problem before posting.  For example, did you check several small values of $n$?  Do you already know an upper bound on the $n$-th prime $p_n$ ?

Comment: Yes I did check it but don't know any other upper bound for primes.

Comment: You might be interested in the [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) of Wikipedia's article on the Prime Number Theorem that gives a lower and an upper bound on $p_n$ for $n \ge 6$, as in the Answer posted by @HAMIDINE.

Answer (score 1):

Test it by hand for $n=1,2,3$. For $n\ge 4$ we know ([Rosser and Schoenfeld (1962)](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255631807), Cor. to Thm. 3) that: $$p_{n+2}<(n+2)\log{(n+2)}+(n+2)\log{\log{(n+2)}}<2n(n+1)+4. $$For the last inequality one can consider the function: $$\phi(x)=2x^2-6x+8-x\log{x}-x\log{\log{x}}, x\ge 4$$ and use differential calculus.

Comment: Can you tell me where can I find more about this?

Comment: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255631807